# Vue Prop not defined, and/or cannot be used on v-for. Using typescript and decorators

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, typescript-decorator

Well, i'm using Vue with typescript and trying to use props with v-for, but it renders nothing. ***Code below***

I've tried computed props, also giving default values to the list and creating a new variable instantiating on constructor, even on mounted, but it only works when i instantiate the list like: `@Prop() list!: string[] = ['foo', 'bar']`

My code gives the following error: "Property or method 'list' is not defined on the instance but referenced during render." (it render the styles for menu but not the list):

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <window-menu :list="['foo', 'bar']" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import WindowMenu from "@/components/WindowMenu.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    WindowMenu
  }
})
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="window-menu">
    <ul class="window-list">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in list" v-bind:key="index">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Prop, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

export default class Menu extends Vue {
  @Prop() private list!: string[];
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your component has been imported as `WindowMenu` but your template has `<menu>`. Try using `<window-menu :list="['foo', 'bar']" />` or `<WindowMenu :list="['foo', 'bar']" />`

Comment: I deleted the 'window' when i edited the question, but it is right on code. My bad, i'm gonna fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed that. Well the error was i was not using the @Component decorator, then Vue could not compile props. **Code fixed below**.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Prop, Vue, Component} from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Menu extends Vue {
  @Prop() private list!: string[];
}
</script>
```